# deep linking working correctly on debug mode but not redirecting correctly on desired page in release mode. (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, flutter-go-router

Deep linking working finely on debug mode but on release mode the deep link only opens the                app but not redirecting on desired page. Issue only exist in debug mode. Here is my project manifest and routes.

````
    ```
    FirebaseDynamicLinks dynamicLinks = FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance;
    Future<void> initDynamicLinks() async {
    dynamicLinks.onLink.listen((dynamicLinkData) {
      String link = dynamicLinkData.link.toString();
      print("Received dynamic link: $link");
      if (uid != null || uid!.isNotEmpty) {
        Get.toNamed("/profile");
      } else {
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
      }
     
      
      }).onError((error) {
      print('onLink error');
      print(error.message);
       });
     }
     ```
````

I want to redirect to desired page on clicking link.

Comment: hi, I have no idea about how to fix your problems, but FYI firebase dynamic links will be shut down within next 12 months.

Comment: Here is a reference to what @HeshanSandeepa is saying:
https://firebase.google.com/support/dynamic-links-faq

You can go ahead and use it though, there is still time. As an alternative, you should look at:
https://pub.dev/packages/app_links